# How to populate cell based off two other cells?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

My spreadsheet has the following columns

```
| A  |  B   |     C     |      D      |
|----|------|-----------|-------------|
| ID | Name | Parent ID | Parent Name |
```

First 3 columns are known. "Parent ID" is either 0 or referring to a number matching the "ID" column. I want to populate the "Parent Name" with the matching value from "Name" and leave it empty is it's 0 or the ParentID doesn't match any IDs.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=C2:C, B2:B, ))
```

[image: 0]